# R column mapping

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

How to map column of one CSV file to column of another CSV file in R. If both are in same data type.
For example first column of data frame A consist some text with country name in it. While column of second data frame B contains a standard list of all country .Now I have to map all rows of first data frame with standard country column.

For example column (location) of data frame A consist 10000 rows of data like this

```
Sydney, Australia
Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark
Auckland, New Zealand
Mumbai Area, India
Singapore
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2=c("Sydney, Australia", "Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark", "Auckland, New Zealand", "Mumbai Area, India", "Singapore"))
```

Now I have another column (country) of data frame B as

```
India
USA
New Zealand
UK
Singapore
Denmark
China
df2 <- data.frame(col1=1:7, col2=c("India", "USA", "New Zealand", "UK", "Singapore", "Denmark", "China"))
```

If location column matches with Country column then, I want to replace that location with country name otherwise it will remain as it is. Sample output is as

```
Sydney, Australia
Denmark
New Zealand
India
Singapore
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a good start but it would be improved if you gave some examples of what you tried.  Also try to put your sample data into a format someone could copy and paste into their R.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Actually I am working huge data set and I have pasted some data from original data set. Currently not getting any idea to get desired output. I have many similar columns to map.I just want a hint how to do it?

Comment: Just take the sample bits you already have and assign them to vectors.   From what you are saying you need to search for match substring or join substring.

Comment: sorry, but i am not getting you.can you help me if I post my data sample to GitHub with problem statement.

Comment: Do you see how @stuski helped you? Now  explain what you found and tried when you searched SO and google for the answer.

Comment: You are really asking three separate things. First, how do you split a string into parts where there are commas. Second, how do you compare one string vector to another string vector and see if the first vector contains an element from the second vector. Third how do you selectively replace the values in a data frame.  Also please say whether the country will always be the last substring.

Comment: yes you are right. Ideally last sub string will be country but some time it may present a  third position or second potion or first position also .As data is collected from internet sources so all data rows are not of similar kind.For example it can be Auckland, New Zealand or just New Zealand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, it looked like a trivial question but it's not. This approach works like this: 
1. We convert the location string into vector using `unlist`, `strsplit`. 
2. Then we check if any string in the vector is available in country column. If it is available, we store the country name in `res` and if not we store `notfound`. 
2. Finally, we check if res contains a country name or not.

```
df1 <- data.frame(location = c('Sydney, Australia',
              'Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark',
              'Auckland, New Zealand',
              'Mumbai Area, India',
          'Singapore'),stringsAsFactors = F)


df2 <- data.frame(country = c('India',
                               'USA',
                               'New Zealand',
                               'UK',
                               'Singapore',
                               'Denmark',
                               'China'),stringsAsFactors = F)


get_values <- function(i)
{
    val <- unlist(strsplit(i, split = ','))
    val <- sapply(val, str_trim)

    res <- c()
    for(j in val)
    {
        if(j %in% df2$country) res <- append(res, j)
        else res <- append(res, 'notfound')
    }

    if(all(res == 'notfound')) return (i)
    else return (res[res!='notfound'])

}

df1$location2 <- sapply(df1$location, get_values)

                           location         location2
1                 Sydney, Australia Sydney, Australia
2 Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark           Denmark
3             Auckland, New Zealand       New Zealand
4                Mumbai Area, India             India
5                         Singapore         Singapore
```

Comment: I'd recommend that df2 actually be a char vector.  No need for it to be a data frame.

Comment: Even I thought that too. But, the question says there are 2 data frame. Although, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). First, please convert your `col2` to character by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because that is easier to work with.

We can use `str_extract` to extract the matched country name, and then create a new `col2` with `mutate` and `ifelse`.

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Country = str_extract(col2, paste0(df2$col2, collapse = "|")),
         col2 = ifelse(is.na(Country), col2, Country)) %>%
  select(-Country)
df3
#   col1              col2
# 1    1 Sydney, Australia
# 2    2           Denmark
# 3    3       New Zealand
# 4    4             India
# 5    5         Singapore
```

We can also start with `df1`, use `separate_rows` to separate the country name. After that, use `semi_join` to check if the country names are in `df2`. Finally, we can combine the data frame with the original `df1` by rows, and then filter the first one for each id in `col1`. `df3` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  separate_rows(col2, sep = ", ") %>%
  semi_join(df2, by = "col2") %>%
  bind_rows(df1) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(col1)
df3
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#    col1 col2             
#   <int> <chr>            
# 1     1 Sydney, Australia
# 2     2 Denmark          
# 3     3 New Zealand      
# 4     4 India            
# 5     5 Singapore
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, 
                  col2=c("Sydney, Australia", "Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark", "Auckland, New Zealand", "Mumbai Area, India", "Singapore"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(col1=1:7, 
                  col2=c("India", "USA", "New Zealand", "UK", "Singapore", "Denmark", "China"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks. I think the OP needs to be careful if there are multiple country names in `col2`. Hopefully the pattern is consistent for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the countries, and they come after the cities then you can do something like this.

```
  transform(df1,col3= sub(paste0(".*,\\s*(",paste0(df2$col2,collapse="|"),")"),"\\1",col2))
  col1                              col2              col3
1    1                 Sydney, Australia Sydney, Australia
2    2 Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark           Denmark
3    3             Auckland, New Zealand       New Zealand
4    4                Mumbai Area, India             India
5    5                         Singapore         Singapore
```

Breakdown:

```
> A=sub(".*,\\s(.*)","\\1",df1$col2)
> B=sapply(A,grep,df2$col2,value=T)
> transform(df1,col3=replace(A,!lengths(B),col2[!lengths(B)]))
  col1                              col2              col3
1    1                 Sydney, Australia Sydney, Australia
2    2 Aarhus C, Central Region, Denmark           Denmark
3    3             Auckland, New Zealand       New Zealand
4    4                Mumbai Area, India             India
5    5                         Singapore         Singapore
```